# PHP Read from Zip Archive

Tags: php, gzip

I have some serialized data in a .gz ( tar then gz ) archive (~ 700MB), which I want to read in PHP without unzipping the same and extract some field out of it.

Have tried PHP : Zip class, however it keeps on giving this error "Can't find EOCD Signature". I have zip extension enabled.

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.95.2.6 2007/05/19 22:35:49 pajoye Exp $
Zip version => 1.8.10
Libzip version => 0.7.1

EDIT : Archive is not corrupted. It works well after unzipping and

Comment: You cannot use Zip to work with Linux gzip archives.

Comment: Same error in perl as well. Tried Perl-Compress-Zlib, Perl-Zip-Archive as well.

Comment: "You can unzip PKZIP/WinZip/etc/ archives using Archive::Zip (that's what it's for) as long as any compressed members are compressed using Deflate compression."

Answer (score 0):

Did you try gzopen ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php

Ignore this line, I am putting it because of the 30 char limit.

Comment: This is put in place because anything < 30 characters is classed as a comment

Comment: So, there can't be an answer under 30 character ?

Comment: +1 for a valid answer, But yes, answer can have some function description to fill 30 char limit instead of comment .